# Starting Sinatra Web Application on Windows

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to Ruby/Sinatra but have inherited a Sinatra application.

I read some documention but am looking for a just a simple way to run the existing Sinatra application.

I've read that [Sinatra-reloader](https://github.com/rkh/sinatra-reloader) is good to start use for development, but I'm just looking to actually startup the web application.

What's the command line command I use to start the application and specify the port? 
The application is currently configured with a config.ru file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use thin or some other webserver:

```
gem install thin
```

Then just pass in the rack config file(config.ru):

```
$ thin -R config.ru start
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

the port in this case is 3000, point browser to 0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: I had to do a bit more finangling, but I got thin working with the help of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/330172/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-thin-server-in-windows